# Array vs If performance inside indexed for loop?

Tags: javascript

Which one has better performance? If statements are more readable but what if I make values in array (database-esque) and make my for loop call the function based on the current index which make it easier for further editing.

```js
var msg = [
  "You are now viewing Tab number one",
  "You are now viewing Tab number two",
  "You are now viewing Tab number three",
  "You are now viewing Tab number four"
]

var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")

for (var i = 0, len = button.length; i < len; ++i) {
  (function(index) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click",
      function() {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg[index];
      });
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<button>Tab1</button>
<button>Tab2</button>
<button>Tab3</button>
<button>Tab4</button>
<br>
<p id="msg">Message here</p>
```

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")

for (var i = 0, len = button.length; i < len; ++i) {
  (function(index) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click",
      function() {
      if (index==0){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "You are now viewing Tab number one";
      }
      if (index==1) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "You are now viewing Tab number two";
      }
      if (index==2) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "You are now viewing Tab number three";
      }
      if (index==3) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "You are now viewing Tab number four";
      }
      });
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<button>Tab1</button>
<button>Tab2</button>
<button>Tab3</button>
<button>Tab4</button>
<br>
<p id="msg">Message here</p>
```

Comment: Did you try to measure it?

Comment: the main thing is, if you have 1000 tabs, array is still easier, but with if you have to write 1000 IFs

Comment: But it requires user input clicking the button to measure it (I think). Where do you suggest I measure this?

Comment: you should not try to optimize, code maintainability and readability come first

Comment: and also accessing array by index is better. say user click tab -100, with ifs it will check 100 conditions, with array, direct index access.

Comment: @D.Seah Exactly. The array is easier to maintain and the if is easier to read, IMO. Curious which one is better. I have seen people make array of trues and falses. I have seen people write loads and loads of ifs. I am kinda curious.

Comment: @AhmedSunny yeah I thought so too but I am not very certain since I don't really know the inner workings of browsers

Comment: you can also use map - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @REDACTEDーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー, performance, it going to be almost the same. btw, in your if implementation, you should have if-else and not just if. I think you should ignore performance for this case.

Comment: @KaranSingh that is I think too sophisticated especially if I want to the button to do other things. I will be limited to the map formatting. Interesting approach though.

Comment: @D.Seah wouldn't if else make it slower because browser check is one by one one instead of all at once?

Comment: "*If statements are more readable*" - I strongly disagree. And, as you said, it does not work when the `msg`s are dynamic, coming from an database.

Comment: @Bergi I have edited my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 4 items, or even 40, performance is irrelevant: computers are very fast and the list is very short. What's more important is how hard it is to read and maintain.

## Performance

But it's worth looking into some underlying performance principles, particularly when it comes to lists, because small lists have an annoying tendency to get large.

An array lookup like `button[i]` is [constant time or O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time). That means no matter how large `button` gets the lookup will always take the same time.

Whereas a succession of if statements, or a [`switch`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp), must try each one until it finds one which matches. Best case is `i` is always 0 and it must compare 1 time. Worst case is `i` is always 3 and it must compare 4 times. If `i` is evenly distributed then it will, on average, take 2 times. This is called [linear time or O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time), the time of the lookup increases as the size of `button` increases. If `button` gets twice as large the time gets twice as long.

With an array lookup as `button` gets larger the performance will remain the same. With if statements as `button` gets larger the performance will get worse.

## Readability

Right now, starting out, you will find linear code easier to read. You'll prefer to have everything in front of you on the page in the order it is executed. But as the code gets more complicated this rapidly becomes overwhelming and will lead to a lot of cutting and pasting code violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): Don't Repeat Yourself.

Experienced programmers find that it's better to push as many details off somewhere else so one can clearly see the important parts. The important part is that it generates click handlers for each button that adds a message from `msg`. What's unimportant is exactly what that message is.

You could make the code even simpler, and possibly save some memory, by extracting the functions from the loop.

```
var addMsgListener = function(element, message) {
  element.addEventListener("click",
    function() {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = message;
    }
  )
};

var buttonMessages = [
  "You are now viewing Tab number one",
  "You are now viewing Tab number two",
  "You are now viewing Tab number three",
  "You are now viewing Tab number four"
]

var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")

for (var i = 0, len = button.length; i < len; ++i) {
  addMsgListener(button[i], buttonMessages[i]);
}
```

Please pardon my possibly awful Javascript.

Now it's very clear what that loop does, for each button it adds a message listener. If I care what a message listener is, I can choose to look at `addMessageListener`. Or I can skip it. This makes the code "skimmable"; one can read the code to get an understanding of what it does and only dive into the details as necessary. It is not a linear read, but that is something you will get used to and come to prefer.

Note that `addMsgListener` no longer refers to `msg` nor `button`. Those are chosen by the loop using it. It is now generic and can be used for other elements and messages.

More reusability will now reveal itself; do the event and id need to be hard coded? This process of changing the code without changing what it does is called [refactoring](https://www.refactoring.com/).

## Maintenance

Every time you want to change a message you have to change code. If you want to add a message, you have to add code and renumber. If you want to remove a message, you have to delete code and renumber. If you want to reorder messages, you have to renumber. This requires a developer for what is a UI change. And the process is error prone, what if you remove a message and forget to change the indexes?

By putting the messages into an array, you only need to change `msg`. If you want to add a message, you add a line to `msg`. If you want to remove a message, you remove a line from `msg`. If you want to reorder the messages, you reorder `msg`.

`msg` does not have to live in the code, it can go into a configuration file making it even easier for a non-coder to change.

## Action at a Distance

This leads us to our final problem: `msg` needs to be the same length and order as there are buttons. Every time the HTML is changed, `msg` might need to be changed, and vice-versa. But the buttons and their messages are in separate locations. This is known as [Action at a Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming)): changing one part of the code is affected by something in a totally different part of the code.

To avoid this, you could give each button a `class` or `id` and index their messages by that. This at least means the buttons and messages don't depend on their exact order. This is useful if you're not sure which buttons will be present in the HTML, but want to have messages for all possible buttons.

```
var msg = {
  car: "",
  truck: "",
  train: "",
  plane: "✈"
}
```

You can go the other way; generate the buttons, and their messages, in the Javascript. It still keeps all the information about each button together. This is useful if the buttons are dynamic and can change.

You can do [as Thomas suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62502438/14660) and attach the messages to the buttons themselves. Then all the data about the buttons is together. If you add, remove, or reorder the buttons the messages still work. This allows one to work on just the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

That's like asking which high-end graphics card should I use for my simple digital clock?
The Performance difference is neglectable. Using an [iife](/questions/tagged/iife) instead of `let` has already a bigger performance impact than your actual question, array index vs. multiple ifs.

And it is still irrelevant.

About the Options, I find them both pretty hard to read, especially as the number of buttons gets bigger.

How about this?

```js
document.querySelector(".buttons").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const button = event.target.closest("button[data-msg]");
  if (button) {
    document.querySelector("#msg").innerText = button.dataset.msg;
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button" data-msg="You are now viewing Tab number one">Tab1</button>
  <button type="button" data-msg="You are now viewing Tab number two">Tab2</button>
  <button type="button" data-msg="You are now viewing Tab number three">Tab3</button>
  <button type="button" data-msg="You are now viewing Tab number four">Tab4</button>
</div>
<p id="msg">Message here</p>
```

imo. nice and declarative. And easy to extend.

The condition `if(button)` deals with the possibility that you might add something else to `div.buttons` that could be clicked on, besides these buttons.

The `.closest("button[data-msg]")` delas with the cases where you might add more markup inside the buttons that might fire the event. We want the `<button data-msg="...">`

Comment: Well, my actual intention is not just displaying messages. If I use this the html will get very dirty very quickly with lots of attributes. I can see that that this is also easier to maintain because if I add more buttons, I don't need to modify the javascript. Very interesting. I will consider this.

Comment: @REDACTEDーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー If you want to use this for tabs, I'd create the actual tabs, not just the buttons, and manage their visibility over `display:none`. You could attach the button labels as attributes to the tabs, or you associate buttons and tabs by an key/index attribute. But in my experience, stay away from injecting content into your code. imo. This will come back and bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tabindex` or `data-index` attribute might be a good idea in this occasion. The example snippet does not involve a loop and uses `data-index`.

```js
var msg = [
  "You are now viewing Tab number one",
  "You are now viewing Tab number two",
  "You are now viewing Tab number three",
  "You are now viewing Tab number four"
]

document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = msg[e.target.dataset['index']];
  }
});
```

```html
<button data-index="0">Tab1</button>
<button data-index="1">Tab2</button>
<button data-index="2">Tab3</button>
<button data-index="3">Tab4</button>
<br>
<p id="msg">Message here</p>
```

**EDIT**

Try to avoid using `tabindex` if you are going to have a large number of tabs. The following part is taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

> Avoid using tabindex values greater than 0. Doing so makes it
> difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and
> operate page content. Instead, write the document with the elements in
> a logical sequence.

Furthermore `tabindex` has a maximum value of 32767.

Comment: Actually, the `tabindex` attribute wasn't created for that... It controls the order in which the *tab*ulator key focuses input fields...

Comment: @FZs not exactly for `input` fields only... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex. In the above case you want to have that order for accessing elements using tab key.

Comment: @PeterDarmis you can make pretty much every element focusable by giving it a `tabindex` != 0. And if you have a second set of these buttons, then your focus will jump 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 from one set of buttons to the other, back and forth as you tab; except for `tabindex="0"`

Comment: @Thomas you write as if you wouldn't check that there are other elements having `tabindex`. The point is to do it properly not having elements with similar `tabindex`. On the other hand if you have seen my answer i write that `data` attributes could be used and for me it is a better approach. Meaning i would do it using `data` attributes e.g. `data-msg` as you wrote in your answer. But there is also a need when writing answers here not to write the same answer as someone else, but up-vote them when they have a point :).

Comment: @PeterDarmis I know this problem. The kind of people who would read this question and copy this code probably not. And about the checking. As soon as you write and use reusable blocks *(functions/components/templates/...)* you can not "check" the indices anymore. It's gets too chaotic. Everything but `tabindex="-1"` is barely manageable.

Comment: @Thomas i made an edit in my answer, explaining more about `tabindex` and it's usage.